# Why can I not use Marshal.Copy() to update a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, managed

I have some code intended to get a struct from a byte array:

```
    public static T GetValue<T>(byte[] data, int start) where T : struct
    {
        T d = default(T);
        int elementsize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

        GCHandle sh = GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.Copy(data, start, sh.AddrOfPinnedObject(), elementsize);
        sh.Free();

        return d;
    }
```

However, the structure `d` is never modified, and always returns its default value.

I have looked up the 'correct' way to do this and am using that instead, but am still curious, as I cannot see why the above should not work.

Its as simple as can be: allocate some memory, d, get a pointer to it, copy some bytes into the memory pointed at by this, return.
Not only that, **but when I use similar code but with d being an array of T, it works fine.**
Unless sh.AddrOfPinnedObject() isn't really pointing to `d`, but then what is the point of it?

**Can anyone tell me why the above does not work?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity what was the 'correct' way?

Comment: @Dmitry, Hi, the correct way is to use PtrToStructure() passing  a pointer to unmanaged memory containing the contents of the struct as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx
Using reflector it can be seen PtrToStructure() instantiates a new object and populates it, though how it does it I am not sure since those details I believe are in the CLR which I cannot see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788625/pinvoke-win32-function-for-marshal-ptrtostructure-in-silverlight-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning implementation detail alert, this may not be true in future versions of .Net.

`structs` are value types and are (generally) stored on the stack (*) , not on the heap. An address of a struct is meaningless since they are passed by value, not by reference. The array of struct is a reference type, that is a pointer to memory on the heap, so the address in memory is perfectly valid.

The point of `AddrOfPinnedObject` is to get the address of an *object* thats memory is pinned, not a *struct*.

Additionally, Eric Lippert has written [a series of very good blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) on the subject of reference types and value types.

(*) Unless:

1 They are fields on a class
 2 They are boxed
 3 They are "captured variables"
 4 They are in an iterator block

(nb points 3 and 4 are corollaries of point 1)

Comment: Should be noted that `structs` can be stored on the `heap`, this will happen when they are members of a `class`

Answer (score 10):

```
    GCHandle sh = GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

That's where your problem started.  A struct is a *value type*, GCHandle.Alloc() can only allocate handles for *reference types*.  The kind whose objects are allocated on the garbage collected heap.  And the kind that make pinning sensible.  The C# compiler is being a bit too helpful here, it automatically emits a boxing conversion to box the value and make the statement work.  Which is normally very nice and creates the illusion that value types are derived from System.Object.  Quacks-like-a-duck typing.

Problem is, Marshal.Copy() will update the *boxed copy* of the value.  *Not* your variable.  So you don't see it change.

Directly updating the structure value is only possible with Marshal.PtrToStructure().  It contains the required smarts to convert the published layout of the struct (StructLayout attribute) to the internal layout.  Which is not the same and otherwise undiscoverable.

Comment: +1 Thank you for explaining the automatic boxing of d; I can see fully how my code is (not!) working now.

Comment: Value types *are* derived from System.Object. It's not an illusion!

Comment: Sure.  If only abstractions would never leak.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(byte[] data, int start) where T : struct
{
    int elementsize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(elementsize);

        Marshal.Copy(data, start, ptr, elementsize);
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

But I would use explicit layout here because of [struct alignment](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 3)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte z;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public short y;
}
```