# pInvoke Win32 function for Marshal.PtrToStructure in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, winapi, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0

I used

```
public static Object PtrToStructure(
IntPtr ptr,
Type structureType
)
```

in the form of

```
private static object ReadStruct(byte[] buffer, Type t)
{
    GCHandle handle =
        GCHandle.Alloc(buffer,
        GCHandleType.Pinned);
    Object temp =
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        t);
    handle.Free();
    return temp;
}
```

for marshaling data in .net 4.0.  Silverlight does not support this method. According to the following article, the .net method is simply a wrapper for a native win32 function. An example was given for Marshal.AllocHGlobal (Win32 LocalAlloc function from Kernel32.dll)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx

These are new waters since SL5 just enabled pInvoke for trusted applications (in browser as well) What is the win32 function that PtrToStructure wraps and is there anything preventing using this in SL5?

Comment: Hard to imagine how a plain Win32 function could synthesise a .net object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a decompiler of your choice, you will be able to see that `PtrToStructure(IntPtr, Type)` is indeed implemented in the *mscorlib.dll* assembly of Silverlight 5:

```
[SecurityCritical]
[ComVisible(true)]
[FriendAccessAllowed]
internal static object PtrToStructure(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)
```

Being `internal` it is however not accessible to other assemblies. `PtrToStructure` in turn calls the following method:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static void PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr ptr, object structure, bool allowValueClasses);
```

which is implemented in the common language runtime.

I have not been able to identify the *win32* function(s) called by `PtrToStructureHelper`. However, since the `PtrToStructure` method holds the `[SecurityCritical]` attribute it is highly likely that Silverlight  *P/Invoke* calls to these *win32* functions, if identified, would lead to security exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ended up recreating the struct using BitConverter as I had originally decorated it with [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]